# How do I make JQuery Color Box show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, colorbox

I am using this plugin:

https://github.com/evoluteur/colorpicker

I am stuck on this step:

```
Now, let's attach it to an existing <input> tag:

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mycolor").colorpicker();
    });
</script>

<input style="width:100px;" id="mycolor" />
```

I am putting the script in the head and obviously the input is in the body.  I ensured that the file paths are right and I get no error.  When I go into mycolor field the color box doesn't show.  I am new to JS and a bit puzzled.  Not sure how to get it to work.  Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting the script at the end of the document, right before your `</body>` tag to ensure that all your DOM elements have rendered prior to the script being loaded.

Comment: @kunalbhat I did as you suggested but it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your HTML, or what you have tried? Hard to say otherwise.

Comment: Have you added jQuery?

Comment: The widget requires a jQuery UI theme to be present, as well as its own included base CSS file (evol.colorpicker.css). Please read the tutorial. It gives you step by step instructions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep reading the directions on that site, it says you must also place this:

```
<div style="width:128px;">
   <input style="width:100px;" id="mycolor" class="colorPicker evo-cp0" />
   <div class="evo-colorind" style="background-color:#8db3e2"></div>
</div>
```

After the `<input>`.

Basically, the absolute minimum is this:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/evol.colorpicker.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link href="css/evol.colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#mycolor").colorpicker();
         });
    </script>
    <div style="width:128px;">
        <input style="width:100px;" id="mycolor" class="colorPicker evo-cp0" />
        <div class="evo-colorind" style="background-color:#8db3e2"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did try that before but it didn't work.  It simply gives me an input box and a div with the light blue color but the widget doesn't show.

Comment: Thanks.  If i wanted to use this for more than one box, how could i do it?

Comment: Have you saved all the necessary files to your local `js` and `css` folders?

Comment: Just add more `<input style="width:100px;" id="mycolor" />` lines, except use different ids and add corresponding `$("#mycolor").colorpicker();` lines in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no, the absolute minimum is this:

```
<link id="jquiCSS" rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="css/evol.colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/evol.colorpicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input id="mycolor" value="#000000" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $('#mycolor').colorpicker()
    });
</script>
```

The color picker puts the extra div tags in for you. The section of the directions that @DevlshOne is referring to shows another way to initiate the colour picker by manually adding the tags yourself, but they are not needed. The instructions aren't the clearest.

You only have to ensure the prerequisites are present: JQuery, JQuery-UI, Any JQuery-UI theme (it will still show without one, but will be transparent), evol.colorpicker.js (or evol.colorpicker.min.js), evol.colorpicker.css, and are loaded before you initiate the color picker.